# Codeigniter pconnect causes xampp exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I had a problem in too many connections, causes by codeigniter configuration, I found that I had to change 'pconnect' parameter to FALSE. But When I did it, Xampp stop running and showing this error :

```
[NetStatTable] Problem loading Netstat TCP table: Returned -1073741823
[EXCEPTION] System Error. Code: 6.
[EXCEPTION] Access violation at address 005AA712 in module 'xampp-control.exe'.
```

Comment: You have to get sure that your MySQL server is working properly, then try to re-install XAMPP or update its version, finally, try to check your machine RAM using a tool such as [**Windows memory diagnostic**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.09.utilityspotlight.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that there're any problem in MySQL server, because it was working for more than 1 year, and when I turn pconnect to FALSE, it generate exception, and when I turn it back to TRUE, it works fine. Notice that I have a XAMPP CP v3.2.1.